# Why I can't use space character in input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
e.fn[l] = function (t) {
  return this.each(function () {
    e.data(this, l) || e.data(this, l, new o(this, t))
  })
}
```

This is a [function](https://github.com/erhno/litebox/blob/master/.gitignore/.js)

When I use this function, I can't use space character in input.

Can someone please explain why ?

Comment: Are you trying to use space as t? What is happening if you try and what do you expect to happen?

Comment: When i click the space key, nothing happens. And if i delet this function, ı can use space character.

Comment: So you're trying to type space into some other box on the page and can't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that's the case, it seems much more likely to have to do with this part of the code: http://github.com/erhno/litebox/blob/master/.gitignore/.js#L53

That part of the code is removing any other javascript that is bound to keyUp so if you have a second script trying to listen for keyUp, that could be the problem.  A better script would use namespaces so it just messes with it's code.  See the very bottom of http://api.jquery.com/off/

Try changing:

```
        e("body").off("keyup").on("keyup",function(o){
            t.options.escKey&&o.keyCode==keyEsc&&t.closeLitebox(),
            t.options.navKey&&o.keyCode==keyLeft&&e(".litebox-prev").trigger("click"),
            t.options.navKey && o.keyCode == keyRight && e(".litebox-next").trigger("click")
        }),
```

To

```
        e("body").off("keyup.litebox").on("keyup.litebox",function(o){
            t.options.escKey&&o.keyCode==keyEsc&&t.closeLitebox(),
            t.options.navKey&&o.keyCode==keyLeft&&e(".litebox-prev").trigger("click"),
            t.options.navKey && o.keyCode == keyRight && e(".litebox-next").trigger("click")
        }),
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But this change did not work. Just if i delete above mentioned function, i can use space but this time my gallery design not work :(

Comment: Is the box you're trying to type in controlled by another JavaScript script? There is some conflict between the two. Deleting that function breaks the gallery so it resolves the conflict but it isn't necessary the problem code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your repyl. I missed some protocols.